# Common Controls Replacement Project - How to get started?

Tags: javascript, dll, activex, hta, wsh

I want to use the [Common Controls Replacement Project](http://ccrp.mvps.org/index.html?controls/ccrpfiledlg6.htm) in my Windows Scripting Host (WSH) HTML Application (HTA). In particular the Extended File Dialogs DLL.

How do I get started?

In my JavaScript I have:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'), OpenDialog = new ActiveXObject('ccrpFileDialog')
```

The first two work OK, but on the third I get an error, "Automation server can't create object." I have already registered "ccrpFD6.dll" using regsvr32.

I don't see any newbie FAQs or discussion groups, so I don't know who else to turn to.

Are there better documented alternatives I can use instead?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it doesn't work that way. It looks like these controls are only intended to be used from VB 5/6 projects, not from VBScript or HTAs.

I registered the DLL version which puts a "ccrpFD_DLL6.ccrpFileDialogDLL" ProgId in the registry.

Calling it with `set fd = WScript.CreateObject("ccrpFD_DLL6.ccrpFileDialogDLL")` produced "H:\projects\ccrpFileDialogTest.vbs(5, 1) **ccrpFD_DLL6: Invalid procedure call or argument**"

I then registered the OCX version which created a ProgId of "ccrFileDialogs6.ccrpFileDialogs".

Calling this in a similar way produced this error: "H:\projects\ccrpFileDialogTest.vbs(6, 1) **WScript.CreateObject: Could not locate automation class named "ccrpFileDialogs".**"

Comment: That's odd because I was able to get [this one](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=186781) to work. Is there a reason one will and one wont function?